# Laravel event dispatch in web.php

Tags: laravel, events, pusher, dispatch

I just wanted to use event broadcasting in Laravel and I followed a tutorial video. But problem shows up in the beginning. The tutorial shows what to do in `web.php` and it goes like this:

```
Route::get( uri: '/'. action: function () {
   eventName::dispatch();
   return view( view: 'welcome');
});
```

The problem is I have a different route formula in my `web.php` which is like this:

```
Route::get('{path}', SpaController::class)->where('path', '(.*)');
```

The question is, how to dispatch the event in my `web.php`?

Comment: The tutorial is showing a quick, no-controller approach. You would call `eventName::dispatch();` within your SpaController.

Comment: Just make sure the routes don't conflict.

Comment: @ceejayoz, i put in spa controller but it says `Class 'App\Http\Events\eventName' not found`. I added this too `use App\Http\Events\eventName;`

Comment: i put within `public function __invoke()` in SpaController

Comment: Is there a file in `app/Http/Events/eventName.php`, with that exact capitalization, and a `namespace App\Http\Events` and `class eventName` in it?

Comment: @ceejayoz my bad. it should be `use App\Events\eventName;`. The problem solved now. i got this in laravel log `"socket": null`. thank you very much. but how can i accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve based on @ceejayoz's comment:

```
   The tutorial is showing a quick, no-controller approach. You would call 
   eventName::dispatch(); within your SpaController.
```